# Getting Size of Float in PHP

Tags: php, memory, floating-point

I would like to check how much memory a floating point number occupies in PHP5. I have read that [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) is not very reliable.

I have used it to try and determine the size of floats, and every time that I create a new floating-point number the memory usage increments by 168 bytes. I thought that this seems too large, so my question is - how reliable is this figure? Is there a better way to approximate the size of floating-point numbers?

My server's OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) returns the amount of memory used by PHP to store the variables of your program and its internal bookeeping of these variables.

There is no direct link between the value returned by `memory_get_usage()` and the amount of memory used to store the actual values handled by your script.

Because the PHP variables don't have a type, each variable uses a data structure that allows it to store values of any type. This means, even for the 1-bit payload of a `bool` value, PHP uses a lot of memory (probably those 168 bytes you measured).

The amount is even bigger when the value is part of an array because an array is a complex type that mixes the structure and functionality of arrays, hashes and double-linked lists. In order to provide the functionality of these different data structures, the array type keeps links between the objects it stores and these links also use memory.

PHP 7 changed the way it stores its data internally and, in average, it reduced the amount of used memory to about one half of the memory used by PHP 5.

However, if you want to know how many bytes are used to store the actual float value (in order to know its range of possible values, f.e.), the information is available in the [documentation page of the float type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> The size of a `float` is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

*I suppose "platform-dependent" means it uses 4 bytes on 32-bit platforms (the traditional size for `float`) and 8 bytes on 64-bit and larger platforms (the traditional `double`).*

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a shame that I'm using a PHP5-only library. I tried my process using PHP7 and it is much faster. Unfortunately, I've got to accommodate to PHP5. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Platform-dependent does not imply 32 bits on 32-bit architectures and 64 bits on 64-bit architectures. Floating-point values are often handled differently than integers, including different registers and different instructions, and are not tied to the architectural width as closely as integers are. The decision would more likely be made based on the processor’s speed and bandwidth of floating-point operations or the desire/demand for precision.