# How to find out the size of a float in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point, integer, size, constants

I'm using **PHP 7.2.5(installed using the latest version of XAMPP)** on my machine that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit operating system**.

As per my knowledge, in PHP, the sizes of an integer and a float are platform-dependent.

PHP has provided a predefined constant `PHP_INT_SIZE` to find out the size of an integer but it has not provided any such constant to find out the size of a float.

So, my question is how should I find out the size of a float in PHP?

P.S. : I've referred the [Previously Asked Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961795/getting-size-of-float-in-php) but couldn't get the reliable, efficient and satisfactory solution for my problem. At the end of an answer of this question the author of the answer is making the below assumption

*I suppose "platform-dependent" means it uses 4 bytes on 32-bit platforms (the traditional size for float) and 8 bytes on 64-bit and larger platforms (the traditional double).*

which is vague I think as it has no more related evidence or proof.

Comment: From the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php): *The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).* This says to me that a float on 32-bit is indeed 4 bytes and on 64-bit is a traditional double and thus 8 bytes. Can't really do anything about you finding it vague, unfortunately :p

Comment: @Loek : I've read the same statement from the docs. Again you are making assumption about size of float in PHP. By means of a predefined constant PHP_INT_SIZE I can get the size of integer as the output. In case of float also I want the size of float as the output and not in the form of some assumption made by someone else. I will believe in your assumption if you can provide me the size of a float in the form of a output of some program.

Comment: @Loek: Platform-dependent does not imply 32 bits on 32-bit architectures and 64 bits on 64-bit architectures. Floating-point values are often handled differently than integers, including different registers and different instructions, and are not tied to the architectural width as closely as integers are. The decision would more likely be made based on the processor’s speed and bandwidth of floating-point operations or the desire/demand for precision.

Comment: Note that since php 7.2, there **is** such a constant: https://3v4l.org/QpHOI

Comment: @EricPostpischil fair enough, good points.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [`pack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function to define a constant.

```
if(!defined('PHP_FLOAT_SIZE'))
    define('PHP_FLOAT_SIZE', strlen(pack('d', 0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of a float is platform dependent, but since PHP 7.2, [there actually **is** a constant `PHP_FLOAT_MAX`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

Because it's platform dependent, there isn't a definite answer. But you can at least see what the max size is on your platform with this constant in PHP 7.2:  https://3v4l.org/QpHOI

To count the bytes, we have to convert that very large float into binary and then we can manually count the bytes, see here: https://3v4l.org/ASZbs

Apparently 3v4l.org can handle some pretty large floats, up to 128 bytes!

Credits to an anonymous user in the PHP docs who [created a function to convert 32+ bit floats into binary](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php#19498) which I blatantly copy pasted.

Comment: The new constant is not giving you the size of a float. It's giving you the maximum float value present for the respective platform. So, this can't be answer to my question.

Comment: So convert the maximum value to binary and count the bytes I guess? Don't have time now, but can try to do that later today.

Comment: @SerialKisser check this (it's crappy copy-pasting but it does the job): https://3v4l.org/ASZbs

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly going to use the IEEE 64-bit format, since this is basically what every platform uses these days. You could add an assertion to that effect, e.g.

```
assert((1.0+pow(2.0,-52))-1 != 0)
assert((1.0+pow(2.0,-53))-1 == 0)
```

will check that the format has exactly 53 significant bits.